# Proper way of displaying an error from controller when the error is in relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My project model has a many to many relationship to Users (members).  I have an invitation form that allows users to enter an email to add members to a project. If the user enters an invalid email address or an email that doesn't correlate to a User in the database, no error is displayed. I would like to provide an error message.  What is the best way of accomplishing this?

I created the `invite` method on the Project model and only running it if the `@user` exists in the invitation controller. I would like to provide an error message that the member wasn't added because the User doesn't exist.

**Invitation Form**

```
<%= form_with(url: "/projects/#{@project.id}/invitation", method: "post") do %>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, class: "border border-gray rounded w-ful py-2 px-3", placeholder: "Email Address", autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag("Invite", class: 'button') %>
<% end %>
```

**Invitation Controller**

```
module Projects
  class InvitationController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user

    # POST /projects/{id}/invitation
    # POST /projects/{id}/invitation.json
    def create
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      if @user
        @project.invite(@user)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        if @project.save
          format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: "User was successfully added." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def set_user
      @user = User.with_email(params[:email]).first
    end
  end
end
```

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  include ActivityRecorder
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :activities, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  has_many :subjects, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, as: 'subject'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members,
                          class_name: 'User',
                          join_table: "members_projects",
                          foreign_key: "projects_id",
                          association_foreign_key: "users_id"

  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :user

  def invite(user)
    self.members << user unless self.members.include?(user)
  end
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :projects
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects_as_member,
                          class_name: 'Project',
                          join_table: "members_projects",
                          foreign_key: "users_id",
                          association_foreign_key: "projects_id"

  scope :with_email, ->(email) { where("email = ?", email) }

  def get_md5_email
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.email)
  end

end
```

**Projects Controller**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_user
  before_action :verify_project_access, only: [:show]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
   @projects = Project.where(user: current_user).or(Project.where(id: current_user)).order('updated_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: "Project was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: "Project was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: "Project was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :notes)
  end

  def verify_project_access
    if @project.user != current_user
      flash[:danger] = "You don't have access this project"
      redirect_to projects_url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a better way to do this but I ended up just simply:

```
if @user
  @project.invite(@user)
else
  redirect_to @project, alert: "Invalid user was entered"
  return
end
```

**Invitation Controller**

```
module Projects
  class InvitationController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user

    # POST /projects/{id}/invitation
    # POST /projects/{id}/invitation.json
    def create
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      if @user
        @project.invite(@user)
      else
        redirect_to @project, alert: "Invalid user was entered"
        return
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        if @project.save
          format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: "User was successfully added." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def set_user
      @user = User.with_email(params[:email]).first
    end
  end
end
```